# How can I get a good-looking display of a large output in a question?

Tags: support

In this [Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103750/a-difficult-precision-problem) both of my displayed outputs are a mess on Chrome.  The first one (with radicals) creates huge parenteses and runs off the right of the page, and the second one (with large integers) runs waaaaay off the right of the page.  Is there a way to fix this?  I just pasted the TeXForm output in between some dollar signs.  I've run into this problem posted a few other questions too.

Answer (score 5):

If you paste the `InputForm`, *Mathematica* will break the integer up, but in a way that can be pasted back into *Mathematica*:

```
1476970928157351816860042743128858490934671778871862601818801179568155\
1674608250556373798213438838903089324192397165503115692398200979544523\
7436098869911125858111671457534293531550227204426557474412874444056537\
5589523598122491930882044615447482230883087076619463975044428225272927\
6599091628027019385080181289731159787444984671454946081033581682364322\
7293330493863411548106839219241822466768921583568955627335268963141029\
6101193045612568151469291529425850567811242123738162398090082254628903\
9363594238495861592432726605188205131294019936846760883091164464285543\
3909402967926 - 
 104437615891545257496417768499303993150192546198507781167667629123050\
9863316110627206227260454120965903445640602087706863031327574125812872\
2132114070519309070230123775812359156216004345017373200971964237001881\
2330693084500590805964215749598013705892215307391548522404846842401369\
8986750819005501472217302202169568300331811215147028898939339794943089\
7213747545170723769636181617027626790881159267053175932151752623087973\
6820859410888074310814279229466095712432316237303167672249609959845163\
6322214327380689081912532243931648371437306541992775161133538382715767\
86201217435197 Sqrt[2]
```

On the other hand, is it necessary to show all this? Maybe this is better, unless you think it's important for people to be able to check your output?

```
(14769...26) - (10443...97) Sqrt[2]  (* digits omitted *)
```

The TeX probably requires some manual intervention:

```
$$\left(\dots\left(\left(\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)^2  -
  \sqrt{2}\right)^2-\sqrt{2}\right)^2 \dots -\sqrt{2}\right)^2-\sqrt{2}$$
```

[image: TeX-example]

Or paste the `InputForm` (I entered some returns in the output cell to get it to break up the output across lines, at places of *my* choosing):

```
-Sqrt[2] + (-Sqrt[2] + (-Sqrt[2] + (-Sqrt[2] + (-Sqrt[2] +
         (-Sqrt[2] + (-Sqrt[2] + (-Sqrt[2] + (-Sqrt[2] +
                 (-Sqrt[2] + (2 - Sqrt[2])^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, MathJax does not work in Meta, so your TeX expression won't display here. I substituted a image made from a screenshot. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks.  (I don't remember, but I thought I saw the formatted TeX after I posted.  Could it be browser dependent? In any case, it's fine the way you did it.)

Comment: The screenshot was made in my browser (Safari) with your TeX expression pasted into the editor on the main _Mathematica_.SE site, so I can't see how it could be my browser.